# Dúvida ListView

Tags: android, android-activity, android-adapter

Tenho o seguinte código abaixo aonde estou com dúvida como eu faço para exibir a lista na tela, já tentei de diversas formas e já fiz vários exemplos da internet não consegui uma solução correta pro meu problema.

O Erro é:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to
>   android.widget.TextView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="br.com.escconsultoria.escoficina.view.AcompanharOrdemServicoActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewAcompanharOrdemServico"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="495dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />
```

```
public class AcompanharOrdemServicoActivity extends Activity {

private ListView listViewAcompanharOrdemServico;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_acompanhar_ordem_servico);

    listViewAcompanharOrdemServico = findViewById(R.id.listViewAcompanharOrdemServico);

    String cpfCliente = null;
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        cpfCliente = extras.getString("cpfCliente");
    }

    new CarregaAcompanharOrdemServicoSaidaDTOJsonAsyncTask().execute("https://escoficinawebservice.herokuapp.com/acompanharOrdemServico/" + cpfCliente);
}

    /*@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    AcompanharOrdemServico acompanharOrdemServico = (AcompanharOrdemServico) l.getAdapter().getItem(position);

    Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(acompanharOrdemServico.url));
    startActivity(it);
    }*/

class CarregaAcompanharOrdemServicoSaidaDTOJsonAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<AcompanharOrdemServicoSaidaDTO>> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        Context context = getApplicationContext();

        String message = "Aguarde... Verificando CPF.";
        int time = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, time);
        toast.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<AcompanharOrdemServicoSaidaDTO> doInBackground(String... params) {
        String urlString = params[0];

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(urlString);

        List<AcompanharOrdemServicoSaidaDTO> listaAcompanharOrdemServicoSaidaDTO = null;

        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

            HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();

            if (httpEntity != null) {
                InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();

                String json = toString(inputStream);
                inputStream.close();

                listaAcompanharOrdemServicoSaidaDTO = getAcompanharOrdemServico(json);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            int time = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            String message = "Erro: " + e.getMessage();

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, time);
            toast.show();

            return null;
        }

        return listaAcompanharOrdemServicoSaidaDTO;
    }

    private List<AcompanharOrdemServicoSaidaDTO> getAcompanharOrdemServico(String jsonString) {

        List<AcompanharOrdemServicoSaidaDTO> listaAcompanharOrdemServicoSaidaDTO = new ArrayList<>();
        AcompanharOrdemServicoSaidaDTO acompanharOrdemServicoSaidaDTO = new AcompanharOrdemServicoSaidaDTO();

        List<AcompanharOrdemServicoModel> listaAcompanharOrdemServicoModel = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObjectConvertString = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            JSONObject jsonObjectEntity = jsonObjectConvertString.getJSONObject("entity");
            JSONArray jsonArrayAcompanharOrdemServicoModel = jsonObjectEntity.getJSONArray("listaAcompanharOrdemServicoModel");

            JSONObject jsonObjectAcompanharOrdemServicoModel;

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayAcompanharOrdemServicoModel.length(); i++) {
                jsonObjectAcompanharOrdemServicoModel = new JSONObject(jsonArrayAcompanharOrdemServicoModel.getString(i));

                AcompanharOrdemServicoModel acompanharOrdemServicoModel = new AcompanharOrdemServicoModel();
                acompanharOrdemServicoModel.setCodigoOrdemServico(jsonObjectAcompanharOrdemServicoModel.getInt("codigoOrdemServico"));

                Long dataCadastroAcompanharOrdemServico = jsonObjectAcompanharOrdemServicoModel.getLong("dataCadastroAcompanharOrdermServico");
                acompanharOrdemServicoModel.setDataCadastroAcompanharOrdermServico(new Date(dataCadastroAcompanharOrdemServico));

                listaAcompanharOrdemServicoModel.add(acompanharOrdemServicoModel);
            }

            acompanharOrdemServicoSaidaDTO.setListaAcompanharOrdemServicoModel(listaAcompanharOrdemServicoModel);


            listaAcompanharOrdemServicoSaidaDTO.add(acompanharOrdemServicoSaidaDTO);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            int time = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            String message = "Erro: " + e.getMessage();

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, time);
            toast.show();

            return null;
        }

        return listaAcompanharOrdemServicoSaidaDTO;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<AcompanharOrdemServicoSaidaDTO> listaAcompanharOrdemServicoSaidaDTO) {
        super.onPostExecute(listaAcompanharOrdemServicoSaidaDTO);


        if (listaAcompanharOrdemServicoSaidaDTO != null) {

            ArrayAdapter<AcompanharOrdemServicoSaidaDTO> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<AcompanharOrdemServicoSaidaDTO>(AcompanharOrdemServicoActivity.this,
                    R.layout.activity_acompanhar_ordem_servico, listaAcompanharOrdemServicoSaidaDTO);

            listViewAcompanharOrdemServico.setAdapter(adapter);

        } else {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    AcompanharOrdemServicoActivity.this).setTitle("Atenção")
                    .setMessage("Não foi possivel acessar essas informções...")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", null);
            builder.create().show();
        }
    }

    private String toString(InputStream is) throws IOException {

        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int lidos;
        while ((lidos = is.read(bytes)) > 0) {
            baos.write(bytes, 0, lidos);
        }
        return new String(baos.toByteArray());
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Repare que o construtor da classe `ArrayAdapter` espera como parâmetro:

1. Um contexto
2. Um layout que será usado para representar cada item da lista. Esse layout, por padrão, deve ter uma TextView
3. Uma lista de objetos

No entanto, quando você chama

```
new ArrayAdapter<AcompanharOrdemServicoSaidaDTO>(AcompanharOrdemServicoActivity.this,
                        R.layout.activity_acompanhar_ordem_servico, listaAcompanharOrdemServicoSaidaDTO);
```

você está passando no 2º parâmetro o layout da `Activity`, que é um `ConstraintLayout` e não um `TextView`, como o esperado, por isso o erro de `ClassCastException`.

Para solucionar esse erro, passe como 2º parâmetro o *id* de um layout que contenha **apenas** um `TextView`. Caso não queira criar um, você pode utilizar o layout `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`, que é fornecido pelo Android.

Answer (score 1):

Faça o que nosso amigo falou acima e para complementar, para que o ArrayAdapter consiga popular sua lista você terá que escrever um

```
@Override
public String toString(){
  return this.variavel;
}
```

no seu DTO substituindo o `this.valiavel` pelo que você quer mostrar na linha do ListView. Caso não faça um toString será impresso uma referência de memória de cada objeto no Array.

Dica: 
Force o Casting nesta linha a seguir para evitar problemas futuros.

```
listViewAcompanharOrdemServico = findViewById(R.id.listViewAcompanharOrdemServico);
```

Resultado:

```
listViewAcompanharOrdemServico = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewAcompanharOrdemServico);
```